# Auto sum fields in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting

When I add fields for this report Visual Studio automatically puts "Sum" in front of the field. Can anyone tell me what this is/how to fix it? For example:

I am trying to add the field "AorFCrnt" into a table. On the drop down list the field is labeled correctly but when it is added to the table it reads [Sum(AorFCrnt)]. It does the same thing for any other field I have available.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this using SSRS?